# Custom Listview with check box in Android SDK

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Hi i am new to Android development ,
How to show Custom Listview with check box in Android SDK. I need selected checkbox should be selected before no need to select.

For example i have a favarote view in that i selected some items previously should appear as selected when i have to go that view.

Please any one help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by **I need selected checkbox should be selected before no need to select.**?

Comment: What i mean that i am showing 10 items in listview. I need to selected checkox 3 which are i previously selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void SaveSelections() {

    // save the selections in the shared preference in private mode for the
    // user

    SharedPreferences settingsActivity = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settingsActivity.edit();

    savedNames = getSavedItems();

    prefEditor.putString(SETTING_TODOLIST, savedNames);

    prefEditor.commit();
}

private String getSavedItems() {
    String savedNames = "";

    int count = this.listView.getAdapter().getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        if (FPhoneListCheckboxAES.phonelist.get(i).getChecked() == true) {

            if (savedNames.length() > 0) {
                savedNames += ","
                        + FPhoneListCheckboxAES.phonelist.get(i).getname();
                savedPhoneno += ","
                        + FPhoneListCheckboxAES.phonelist.get(i).getphoneNo();

            } else {
                savedNames += FPhoneListCheckboxAES.phonelist.get(i).getname();
                savedPhoneno += FPhoneListCheckboxAES.phonelist.get(i)
                        .getphoneNo();

            }
        }

    }
    return savedNames;
}
```

check the link this will help u a lot

http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/12/listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes/